# Populate a listbox with two tables

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a userform to save entries from userform to my worksheet. I have code to show what is saved in the worksheet, in a listbox on the form:

```
Sub spl2list()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL2_Steel")
Dim lr As Long
lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row

If lr = 7 Then lr = 8

With Me.ListBox_spl2
     .ColumnCount = 18
     .ColumnHeads = True
     .ColumnWidths = "150,150,150,150,150,150,150,190,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150"
     .RowSource = "PL2_Steel!A8:R" & lr
End With

End Sub
```

This code shows the table columns (with headers which is row 7 and data which are row 8 to Ir), from one table (Range A8:R).

Now I need to show two tables in this list, the second coming right after the first one. So if the first one has 18 columns, I want column 19 of listbox to be the first column of my second table and so one till the end of the second table.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to do what your want.

Basically, there are 3 ways to fill a listbox:

The first is (as you do) to assign a Range to the property `RowSource` and you're done. However, this doesn't work for Ranges that are non-contiguous. So if your 2nd table is on another sheet, this will not work.

The second is to add the data manually by using the method `.add`. With every `Add`, a new row is created (with data on the first column). To fill additionally columns, you can access the property `.List` which is basically a 2-dimensional array (starting with index 0). So `.List(0, 1) = "Hallo"` would  write a string into the 2nd field of the first row. However, this method is limited to 10 columns.

The third is to prepare a 2-dimensional array holding all the data and assign it to the `List`-property: `List = myArray`.

To use the 2nd or 3rd method, you would need to write some code that loops over both of your ranges and fill the data cell by cell. However, it has a big disadvantage: You cannot have automatic column headers (if you set `.ColumnHeaders = True`, the headers will be displayed blank.

---

The best idea I have is to create a helper sheet that references both of your tables next to each other. You can set this sheet to hidden so the users will not notice. As the data is only referenced (and not copied), there shouldn't be any performance issues.

The following code will create and fill such a sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Function CreateListboxDataRange() As Range

    ' Get Ranges with data
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = getSourceRange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL2_Steel").Range("A8"))
    Set r2 = getSourceRange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Another Sheet").Range("wherever"))
    
    ' Prepare a temp. Sheet referencing data from both ranges.
    Dim tmpSheet As Worksheet
    Set tmpSheet = getTEMPSheet()
    tmpSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents
    tmpSheet.Range("A1").Formula2 = "='" & r1.Parent.Name & "'!" & r1.Address
    tmpSheet.Range("A1").Offset(, r1.Columns.Count).Formula2 = "='" & r2.Parent.Name & "'!" & r2.Address
    
    Dim rowCount As Long, colCount As Long
    colCount = r1.Columns.Count + r2.Columns.Count
    rowCount = WorksheetFunction.Max(r1.Rows.Count, r2.Rows.Count)
    
    Set CreateListboxDataRange = tmpSheet.Range("A1").Resize(rowCount, colCount)
    
End Function

Function getSourceRange(startCell As Range) As Range
    ' Helper function to return a Range with the correct number of rows and columns
    With startCell.Parent
        Dim lastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
        LastCol = startCell.End(xlToRight).Column
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Set getSourceRange = startCell.Resize(lastRow - startCell.Row + 1, LastCol - startCell.Column + 1)
    End With
End Function

Function getTEMPSheet() As Worksheet
    ' Create the helper sheet if it is not present.
    Const TMPSheetName = "TMP"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set getTEMPSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TMPSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If getTEMPSheet Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        Set getTEMPSheet = ActiveSheet
        getTEMPSheet.Name = TMPSheetName
        getTEMPSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden 
    End If
End Function
```

Now the code in your form is rather simple:

```
Sub fillListbox()
    With Me.ListBox_spl2
        Dim sourceRange As Range
        Set sourceRange = CreateListboxDataRange
        ' Remove the first row because it will be used as Caption row automatically 
        Set sourceRange = sourceRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count - 1)

        ' Set the Columns of the Grid
        .columnCount = sourceRange.Columns.Count
        ReDim colWidth(1 To .columnCount) As String
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .columnCount
            colWidth(i) = 150
        Next
        .ColumnWidths = Join(colWidth, ",")

        ' Assing the Range as RowSource. 
        .RowSource = "'" & sourceRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & sourceRange.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for your perfect explanation. Actually I always hesitate making an extra sheet. But of course if it disappears afterwards it is fine then. I will give the code a try.

Comment: I understand your hesitation. But as the sheet can be hidden and contains absolute no data, the overhead is really small and the user will not notice at all.