Why I could not simply read sheets and merge all the content in a single Variant?
Context: I'm trying, in VBA / Excel, to read the content of multiple large sheets (arround ~100k rows in total) and to store it in a Variant in order to work on the data in memory.
Why : I want to work on this data in memory to gain speed, instead of working and writing on the sheets directly
My code was working well with one sheet, the problems begins when there is more than one sheet.
The problem : I want to join the content of the different sheets in only one Variant, in order to work on it
The code :
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arrData As Variant ' The variant to store the data
Dim lastSheetLine As Double
Dim lineMemory As Double

lineMemory = 0

For Each ws In ThisWorkBook.Worksheets ' Parse all the sheets

     lastSheetLine = Worksheets(ws.name).Cells(Worksheets(ws.name).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' find the last line of the sheet

   If lineMemory = 0 Then
     arrData(0, 15) = Worksheets(ws.name).Range("A2:O" & lastSheetLine).Value ' Store the sheet on the Variant
     lineMemory = lastSheetLine
   Else
     lineMemory = lineMemory + lastSheetLine ' Increment to get the position where to put the block
     arrData(lineMemory, 15) = Worksheets(ws.name).Range("A2:O" & lastSheetLine).Value
   End If

Next ws

In this multi-dimensional array, the second dimension is always 15 (there is always the same number of columns), it is the first dimension that will change from sheet to sheet.
Thanks a lot in advance for your help, I'm open for everything

You can read an entire table from a worksheet into a variant array in one statement, but the syntax is different from yours: varArray = Range("address goes here").Value But you cannot append the data from another range to that same array in one statement. You'll have to use two variant arrays: one that gets the data from the sheets and another which you append the data to. the latter will have to be done row-by-row and column-by-column. Final remark: replace all instances of "Worksheets(ws.name)." with just "ws. "

It looks, you do not understand very well how the arrays work, no offence... You cannot use an array in the way you try.  Then, "My code was working well with one sheet" cannot be true, related to the code you show. arrData(0, 15) = anything You cannot simple add rows and columns to an existing array. You can add columns, but only after ReDim Preserve. The process of merge areas is completely different. About "this multi-dimmensional array" is an incorrect definition. What you try returning (in a wrong way) would be a simple 2D array. Having only two dimensions (rows and columns)...

@jkpieterse thanks for your reply, I'm already using Value (Right, no ?)

@FaneDuru thanks for your reply too ; I confirm you the code was working well with one sheet, because I used directly arrData = X, and no arrData(0, 15) ; because there was only one sheet, I did not had the problem to merge and joins multiples content block in one array ; what would be your solution to merge two 2D array ?

Are you sure you want to put all data of all Worksheets into one array before working with it? It will get hard to write the data back to the sheets because you would need to keep track of where the data of every sheets starts+ends. If I were you, I would use one array per sheet.

@FunThomas Thanks for your reply Thomas ; Yes I want to work on one array only, because I do not neet to get the data back to the sheets, it is a one-way routine, and therefore there is in one of the colums an ID which could help me to get it back if necessary

Then, please test the code I posted and send some feedback.

To merge arrays having the same number of columns, please try the next way:

Declare a variable on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):

  Private arrFin()


Copy the next code in the same standard module:

Sub TestMrgeArrays()
 Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 For Each ws In wb.Worksheets ' Parse all the sheets
     lastRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row ' find the last line of the sheet
     merge2DArrays ws.Range("A2:O" & lastRow).Value ' merge with the final one...
 Next ws
 Debug.Print UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2): Stop
End Sub

Sub merge2DArrays(arr)
    Dim arrNew(), i As Long, j As Long, xF As Long
    
    If Not Not arrFin Then
        If UBound(arrFin, 2) <> UBound(arr, 2) Then MsgBox "Different number of columns...": Exit Sub
        ReDim arrNew(1 To UBound(arrFin) + UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(arrFin, 2))
        xF = UBound(arrFin)
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrNew)
            For j = 1 To UBound(arrNew, 2)
                If i <= xF Then
                    arrNew(i, j) = arrFin(i, j)
                Else
                    arrNew(i, j) = arr(i - xF, j)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        arrFin = arrNew
    Else
        arrFin = arr: Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

There is another option involving ReDim Preserve which can take the previous loaded array, transpose it and place the content in a new array, load it only with the new array content and finally equalize the final array with this (temporary) one. But Transpose has some limitations in terms of range dimensions and it will fail in your case. I can also make a non standard function transposing without error, but it will need iteration also...
Edited:
The next version uses a jagged array (an array of arrays) to be firstly loaded with each sheet array and be processed in a separate function:
Sub TestMrgeArrays_JGGArray()
 Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, arrData() As Variant
 Dim lastRow, arrFin, iCount As Long, totCount As Long

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 ReDim arrData(wb.Worksheets.count - 1) 'ReDim it to keep all the sheets (0 based 1D array)
 For Each ws In wb.Worksheets ' Parse all the sheets
     lastRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row ' find the last line of the sheet
     arrData(iCount) = ws.Range("A2:O" & lastRow).Value ' place it in the jagged array
     iCount = iCount + 1:  totCount = totCount + lastRow - 1 ' -1 because the array is loaded from the second row...
 Next ws
 arrFin = MergeShArrays(arrData, totCount)
 Debug.Print UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2): Stop
End Sub

Function MergeShArrays(arrD, totCount As Long) As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, iRow As Long, colNo As Long, arr, arrNew()
  colNo = UBound(arrD(0), 2)
  ReDim arr(1 To totCount, 1 To colNo)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrD)
    arrNew = arrD(i)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrNew)
        iRow = iRow + 1
        For k = 1 To colNo
            arr(iRow, k) = arrNew(j, k)
        Next k
    Next j
  Next i
  MergeShArrays = arr
End Function

It should be a little faster determining the total number of rows from the sheets iteration part.

I have to thank you, it's working like a charm ; wish you a great end of week, respectfully

about the edited code version, it doesn't work : execution error 13 type incompatibility at the line "For j = 1 To UBound(arrD(i)) in the function

@C K I tested the above code on my computer and it works as it should (Excel 2016 64 bit on Windows 11). Some VBA versions are  not able to cast/understand that the jagged array element is also an array. So you need to declare another variable and... In fact, I will be at home in 1, 2 minutes and I will adapt the code...

@C K Please, test the adapted function. I only declared a new variable (arrNew()) and gave to it the value of arrD(i). (arrNew = arrD(i)). Then use it instead... Does it work as you need? Theoretically, it should be faster. Some less necessary iterations...

Helpful & instructive +:); fyi posted an alternative via dynamic temp sheet built only of direct tabular formulae insertion. @FaneDuru

You can read the values of a range into a Variant variable. If the range contains only one cell, the Variant will get that value. If the range contains more that one cell, the Variant will be a 2-dimensional array.
The destination of that read must be a Variant. It can't be a predefined array:
ReDim a(1 To 10, 1 To 15) 
' This will give a runtime error 13 (Type mismatch)
a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:O10").Value

Dim b()
' This will give a runtime error 13 (Type mismatch)
b = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:O10").Value

Dim c As Variant
' Only this is okay:
c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:O10").Value

And, as a consequence, you can't read the data of a Range into a part of a predefined array (except if the Range contains only a single cell).
So if you really need one big array containing all data of all sheets, you need to create this array by yourself.

The following code will read the data of every sheet separately into a collection of 2-dimensional arrays. While reading, the total size is calculated.
When reading is done, we know how large the final array needs to be. An array is created and all the data is copied into it, sheet by sheet, value by value.
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Data As New Collection
Dim totalRows As Long

' Step 1: Read data of every sheet into separate arrays
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' Parse all the sheets

    Dim lastSheetLine As Long
    lastSheetLine = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row ' find the last line of the sheet
    Data.Add ws.Range("A2:O" & lastSheetLine).Value, ws.Name
    totalRows = totalRows + (lastSheetLine - 1)
Next

' Step 2: Now Copy all data into one big array
ReDim AllInOneData(1 To totalRows, 1 To 15)
Dim allInOneRow As Long, sheetIndex As Long, row As Long, col As Long
For sheetIndex = 1 To Data.Count
    For row = 1 To UBound(Data(sheetIndex), 1)
        allInOneRow = allInOneRow + 1
        For col = 1 To UBound(Data(sheetIndex), 2)
            AllInOneData(allInOneRow, col) = Data(sheetIndex)(row, col)
        Next col
    Next row
Next sheetIndex

Note that you don't need to write Worksheets(ws.name).Cells when ws is already a Worksheet. Simply write ws.Cells.

Thanks for your help ; unfortunately, when I compile the code, Excel froze and shut down (I can't even stop the execution by using Ctrl + Stop button), don't worry the code of @FaneDuru works. I have to thank you for all your help and your time, you helped me a lot !

Fine answer +:); fyi posted an alternative using an earlier helper function of yours. @FunThomas

Alternative benefitting from the newer dynamic array features
Instead of reading all elements of multiple arrays into a total array, this approach

appends only dynamic range formulae per worksheet (like e.g. =A2:O100000) into a hidden temporary worksheet and
assigns the dynamic blocks into total array data in one go.

As this solution reduces the interaction between direct tabular Excel calculation and VBA to a minimum (not to speak of row wise loops), it should profit from a good or even better time behaviour.
Sub MrgArrays()
Const firstRow = 2, firstCol = "A", lastCol = "O"
'0) define array of needed sheets (or choose empty array for ALL sheets)
    Dim SheetNames As Variant
    SheetNames = Array("Tabelle1", "Tabelle3") '<< define only needed sheets
'1) use temporary worksheet
    Dim temp As Worksheet
    Set temp = getTempSheet(ClearIt:=True)
'2) get individual sheet data address
    Dim nxt As Long: nxt = firstRow         ' start temp sheet row counter
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames)
    'a) find last sheet row
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = ws.cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Name = temp.Name Then lastRow = 0
    'b) define next sheet address & add further dynamic formula to temp sheet
        Dim addr As String
        If lastRow >= firstRow Then
            'define next sheet address
            addr = firstCol & firstRow & ":" & lastCol & lastRow
            'add dynamic formula to temporary sheet
            temp.Range("A" & nxt).Formula2 = "=" & ws.Range(addr).Address(external:=True)
            'increment nxt
            nxt = nxt + lastRow - firstRow + 1
        End If
    Next
'3) build total array of temp sheet data
    lastRow = temp.cells(temp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim data As Variant
    data = temp.Range(firstCol & firstRow & ":" & lastCol & lastRow).Value2
End Sub

Helper function getTempSheet() (thx @funthomas)
Function getTempSheet(Optional wsName As String = "TEMP", _
    Optional ByVal ClearIt As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal HideIt As Boolean = True) As Worksheet
'Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76719083/populate-a-listbox-with-two-tables/76721164#76721164
'Auth: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599798/funthomas
'Note: adapted 2024-06-28 by T.M. (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m)
'Purp: Create the helper sheet if it is not present.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set getTempSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0                 ' referenced sheet is not present
    If getTempSheet Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        Set getTempSheet = ActiveSheet
        getTempSheet.Name = wsName
    End If
    ' optional code lines
    If ClearIt Then getTempSheet.cells.Clear                
    getTempSheet.Visible = IIf(HideIt, xlSheetHidden, xlSheetVisible)
End Function


I voted your code up. But only due to the fact I (like to believe) I know you... Many year before I used to be a virtuoso of formulas. Until the workbook became huge and everything was slowed down considerably. Since then, I do not trust in the formulas power, anymore. Until  now, nothing proved (to me) that any formulas applied on huge ranges can be faster than VBA working in memory. But this does not mean that you cannot be right. Did you test this way on a range containing 100k rows? Is it comparable in terms of speed with the arrays method?

@FaneDuru Thanks for comment; after a quick test it seems that from 4 worksheets onwards my solution with 100000 rows and 15 columns is faster.

OK, I will copy the code and also try using this solution in the future. When you say newer dynamic array features, what do you mean? Since when this method is available in VBA? But simple placing consecutive ranges in an array and copy them one after the other wouldn't it be faster? Did you try it? I still do not like formulas for mass processing...

Apprec.feedback: The improved speed of Excel since 64bit (vs. 2010) and especially with MS365 also makes the use of formulas more attractive than before. Of course, calculations in memory are to be favored, but the targeted use of formulas can also be useful - what really slows things down is the interaction between Excel and VBA, e.g. when looping through ranges row by row.
My approach was to limit the assignment to arrays, to use n times mini formulas with a single overall assignment instead of n times 100,000 loops. - Unfortunately, I haven't had time for a systematic test yet. @FaneDuru

Retrieve Data From All Sheets

Application
Sub GetDataFromAllSheetsTEST()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetDataFromAllSheets(wb, , True)
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Continue working with the data...
    
End Sub

The Helper Function
Function GetDataFromAllSheets( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    Optional ByVal HeaderRowsCount As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal DisplayMessages As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get Data From All Sheets"
    
    ' Validate number of worksheets.
    
    Dim iwCount As Long: iwCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    If iwCount = 0 Then
        If DisplayMessages Then
            MsgBox "No worksheets found in " _
                & IIf(Len(wb.Path) = 0, "the never saved ", "") _
                & "workbook """ & wb.Name & """" _
                & IIf(Len(wb.Path) = 0, "", " located in """ & wb.Path & """") _
                & "!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Loop through the worksheets to create a reference to each range
    ' in the 1st column and return the number of rows in the 2nd column
    ' of the Worksheets Data array ('wsData').
    
    Dim wsData() As Variant: ReDim wsData(1 To iwCount, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, wCount As Long
    Dim srCount As Long, cCount As Long, trCount As Long, tcCount As Long
    Dim IsColumnsCountDetermined As Boolean, IsNoDataInSheet As Boolean
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Assuming the list starts in 'A1' with no empty rows or columns.
        With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            srCount = .Rows.Count - HeaderRowsCount
            If srCount > 0 Then
                Set rg = .Resize(srCount).Offset(HeaderRowsCount)
                cCount = .Columns.Count
            Else
                IsNoDataInSheet = True
            End If
        End With
        If IsNoDataInSheet Then
            IsNoDataInSheet = False
        Else
            If Not IsColumnsCountDetermined Then
                tcCount = cCount
                IsColumnsCountDetermined = True
            End If
            If cCount <> tcCount Then
                MsgBox "The number of columns is different in worksheet """ _
                    & ws.Name & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
                Exit Function
            End If
            wCount = wCount + 1
            Set wsData(wCount, 1) = rg
            wsData(wCount, 2) = srCount
            trCount = trCount + srCount
        End If
    Next ws
        
    ' Validate the number of worksheets with data (ranges).
    
    If wCount = 0 Then
        If DisplayMessages Then
            MsgBox "No data found in " _
                & IIf(Len(wb.Path) = 0, "the never saved ", "") _
                & "workbook """ & wb.Name & """" _
                & IIf(Len(wb.Path) = 0, "", " located in """ & wb.Path & """") _
                & "!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Loop through the Worksheets Data array and return the values
    ' from each range in the resulting Total array ('tData').
    
    Dim tData() As Variant: ReDim tData(1 To trCount, 1 To tcCount)
    
    Dim sData() As Variant, w As Long, sr As Long, tr As Long, c As Long
    
    For w = 1 To wCount
        srCount = wsData(w, 2)
        If srCount + cCount = 2 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = wsData(w, 1).Value
        Else
            sData = wsData(w, 1).Value
        End If
        For sr = 1 To srCount
            tr = tr + 1
            For c = 1 To tcCount
                tData(tr, c) = sData(sr, c)
            Next c
        Next sr
    Next w
    
    GetDataFromAllSheets = tData
    
    If DisplayMessages Then
        MsgBox "Retrieved data from " & wCount & "(out of " & iwCount _
            & ") worksheet" & IIf(iwCount = 1, "", "s") & "." & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Number of rows: " & trCount & vbLf _
            & "Number of columns: " & tcCount, vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    
End Function

